# How to simulate/test a PostgreSQL Transaction Rollback Error?

Tags: python, postgresql, concurrency, transactions, psycopg2

An application regularly throws a [TransactionRollbackError](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.TransactionRollbackError) and I have a hard time finding out why it is thrown.

The error message is as follows:

```
TransactionRollbackError: could not serialize access due to concurrent update
```

Unfortunately, these exceptions only occur in the production environment and not in my environment.

I would like to simulate such an error myself. But what should I do? Should I insert a record in the same table? Should I edit the same record as the application does? Should I place a lock somewhere? On a table? A single row?
The name and message suggest that multiple transactions try to update the database. And a transaction rollback is involved, so it seems.

**EDIT**: Now I found out what was causing the problem: Lets say transaction 1 updated a value on Table A, record X. Another, transaction 2, inserted a value in Table B, with a foreign key to Table A - record X. As soon as transaction 1 is committed, transaction 2 gets the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."table_a" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR SHARE OF x"
```

*I think this happens:*

Transaction 2 needs record X (to complete successfully). Transaction 1 has locked record X and therefore Transaction 2 gets this error.

Comment: This error message -- and why it happens -- are explicitly [mentioned in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ).

Comment: @pozs so how do I simulate this? I tried it with 2 psql sessions, but that doesn't throw such an exception.

Comment: Did you identify which query exactly is leading to this error?

Comment: @pozs: in psql sessions I should have set the following: `set transaction isolation level repeatable read;`

Comment: I now found out that the entire record can clash. If one transaction changes the first column and the second transaction updates the 2nd column, it still leads to the same exception!

Comment: @taper you should set your transaction isolation levels like in your production environment. I'm afraid 2 psql sessions is not enough -- theoretically it *can* be enough, but timing is really important here, and you have almost no tool to ensure both sessions affect your server at the (almost) exact same time.

Comment: @taper locking is row-level, not column-level. that wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @pozs Thanks for your help: With the documentation and setting the isolation level I can now simulate the production situation! Thanks

Comment: PostgreSQL has a utility in the source tree called `isolationtester` that lets you write concurrency simulation scripts for this sort of thing. It is very handy. See `src/test/isolation`.

Comment: @taper: You should create an answer showing the details of how you made this possible.